# How do you format a 10 digit string into a phone number?

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I have database records in the form of 10 character long strings, such as 4085551234.

I wish to format these into this format: (408) 555-1234.

I think this is regex related. I'm new to programming and completely self-taught here, so any sort of resource relating to performing text processing would be appreciated as well. Thanks!

Comment: what is the db technology (mysql)?

Comment: Just an aside-- phone number formats vary WIDELY across the globe, so unless you're sure you're only ever displaying US or similar style numbers, you might not want to hardcode a specific format.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5872200/386579

Answer (score 99, accepted):

A regex is definitely overkill for this one.  If you wanted to take a "phone number" and normalize it to 10 digits, that would be a good use for a regex.  To do what you're asking, just do something like:

```
echo '('.substr($data, 0, 3).') '.substr($data, 3, 3).'-'.substr($data,6);
```

Since you already know how to divide up your data, you can just use substr or something similar to grab the parts you want.  RegEx is useful for matching strings which don't always have a strict format. (Like variable numbers of spaces, variable stuff before or after it, extra dashes, etc).  But in your case the input is always strictly formatted 10 digits, nothing else, so you don't need the extra overhead of a RegEx to format it.

Comment: I like the methodology behind this one the most. Thanks a lot! I can see how you did what you did, and I learned a bit about substr(). Thanks!

Comment: Single quotes will work fine here since it doesn't need to be processed.

Answer (score 21):

Take a look here: [Format phone number](http://snipplr.com/view/25/format-phone-number/)

```
function format_phone($phone)
{
    $phone = preg_replace("/^\d/", "", $phone);

    if(strlen($phone) == 7)
        return preg_replace("/(\d{3})(\d{4})/", "$1-$2", $phone);
    elseif(strlen($phone) == 10)
        return preg_replace("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/", "($1) $2-$3", $phone);
    else
        return $phone;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably go with

```
$num = "4085551234";  // given                                                  
$formatted = "(".substr($num,0,3).") ".substr($num,3,3)."-".substr($num,6);
```

Regex isn't really appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks! Similar to the above mentioned solution I went with.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially you could do something like:

```
\(\d\{3\}\)\(\d\{3\}\)\(\d\{4\}\)
```

To match the 10 digits into 3 subgroup expressions, and then print them out using each subgroup:

```
"(\1) \2-\3
```

But in practice free form data is usually a little trickier

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this question for my advanced placement computer science class. 
Java:

> Write a program that accepts a 10 digit # and formats it as a phone number.
>
> Ex: `705726552`
>     Output: `(705)726-2552`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class  TelNumCorrection{

  public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a 10 digit number");
    String num=scan.nextLine();

    String a=num.substring(0,3);
    String b=num.substring(3,6);
    String c=num.substring(6);
    System.out.println("("+a+ ")"+b+"-"+c);
  }
}
```

Comment: it does answer the question, it provides a program to scan and then format/print numbers as requested in question

Comment: This question is tagged with php, as such this answer does not seem relevant.