# PHP to strip not integers and reformat the output as phone number

Tags: php, mysql, string, integer, reformatting

I am trying to make a way that phone numbers being inserted into the database all go in following the same convention regardless of how they are inserted.

so `(123) 456.7890` and `123.456.7890`

would both end up going into the database as `123-456-7890`

Im thinking there has to be a function that will allow me to strip all non Integer characters so `123.456.7890` could be turned into `1234567890` and then reformat it as `xxx-xxx-xxxx`

Perhaps im wrong about this but im thinking php has to have a way of accomplishing something along these lines so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Remove any non-number character
$str = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);
// Insert dashes
$str = preg_replace('/(\d)(?=(\d{4}|\d{7})$)/', '$1-', $str);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pQlwVw

Answer (score 1):

Just a trivial regex would do it:

```
$nums = preg_replace("/\D/","",$input);
```

Ideally you should save it as that and only format it in the output, which would be done like this:

```
$output = preg_replace("/(...)(...)(....)/","$1-$2-$3",$nums);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work (stolen from [How do you format a 10 digit string into a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089923/how-do-you-format-a-10-digit-string-into-a-phone-number))

```
$phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
echo "(".substr($phone, 0, 3).") ".substr($phone, 3, 3)."-".substr($phone,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex for a 7 or 10 digit number, with extensions allowed, delimiters are spaces, dashes, or periods:

```
^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$
```

Or you could use the sledgehammer approach: just strip out anything non-numeric and format to your heart's content.